# Variance stabilization of Scaled Noncentral Chi-squared

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity, variance-stabilizing

For an integer $k > 0$, $\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $\zeta_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $1 \leq i \leq k$. In the background we are taking $k \to \infty$.

Then the random variable $T$ has a scaled [Noncentral $\chi^2 (k , \lambda)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution):

$$
\begin{align}
T &= \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i = 1}^k (\mu_i + \zeta_i)^2, \\
\lambda &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i^2.
\end{align}
$$

In other words, $T = T^{\lambda, k}$ is a two-parameter family:

- with mean $\mu = 1 + \lambda/k$
- with variance $2(1 + 2\lambda/k) = 2(2\mu  - 1)$

Note the strong (linear) dependence between mean and variance. Applying a [variance-stabilizing transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation), we recognize the variance of $T^{\lambda, k}$ as $h(\mu) = 2(2\mu - k)$ and therefore the delta-method-approved transformation is $f(\cdot; \lambda)$ given by

$$
\begin{align}
f(t; \lambda)
&\propto \int_{t_0}^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{h(\mu)}}  \\
&= C_1 \sqrt{t - 1/2} + C_0
\end{align}
$$

for arbitrary $C_1$ and $C_0$.

But obviously $\mathbb{P}(T < 1/2) > 0$, so $f$ can't be applied to all inputs.
So is $T^{\lambda, k}$ not strictly variance-stabilizable?

- Finally, I am aware of [transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Approximation_(including_for_quantiles)) that make $T$ more normal, such as a cube root and others.
- I understand that if we approximate $f(t) = 2\sqrt t$ then $\operatorname{var} f(t) \approx 4 - 1/(1 + \lambda/k)$ which is already not bad. But I, of course, would like to do better.
- I also understand that by Chebyshev's inequality, $\mathbb{P}(T < 1/2) \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. Indeed, the delta method is completely local in $f$ as long as $f(T)$ is a well-behaved random variable, so we could as well define
  \begin{align}
  f(t) &= \begin{cases} \sqrt{t - 1/2}, & t \geq 1/2 \\
  0, &t < 1/2
  \end{cases} 
  \end{align}
  or even something creative like
  \begin{align}
  f(t) &= \begin{cases} \sqrt{t - 1/2}, & t \geq 1/2 \\
  -\sqrt{1/2 - t}, &t < 1/2
  \end{cases} 
  \end{align}
  or even branch cut to
  \begin{align}
  f(t) &= \begin{cases} \sqrt{t - 1/2}, & t \geq 1/2 \\
  i\sqrt{1/2 - t}, &t < 1/2
  \end{cases} 
  \end{align}